# Carregar url na mesma pagina

Tags: php, json, sms

Comprei o serviço de uma empresa de SMS. Mas para enviar o SMS tenho que "rodar" o link abaixo:

```
https://site.com/apiJSON.php?data={"login":"email@email.com.br","senha":"SENHA","campanha":"ID 1234","mensagens":{"1":{"numero":"2799999999","msg":"MINHA MENSAGEM","data":"2016-08-11 09:20:00"}}}
```

Basicamente uma chamada JSON.

O problema é que preciso que envie o SMS no meio de uma função PHP. E não consigo chamar esse link para enviar o SMS.

Alguém tem uma ideia?

Comment: Qual é o problema que você está tendo para usá-la?

Comment: É q nao tenho ideia de como chamar ela pra "rodar" entende. Se colar esse link coms os parametros corretos na barra de endereços e apertar enter ele envia a msg. O problema é q nao sei como rodar o link pelo PHP.

Comment: Um Redirect não funcionaria, para seu problema?                                               http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php) para formatar o *json*, e [`curl`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.curl.php) para fazer o pedido:

```
function enviarSMS($email, $senha, $numero, $msg){
    $curl = curl_init("https://site.com/apiJSON.php?data=");
    $data = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $array = array('login' => $email,
                   'senha' => $senha,
                   'campanha'  => 'ID 1234',
                   'mensagens' => array('1' => array('numero' => $numero,
                                                     'msg' => $msg,
                                                     'data' => $data)));

    $json = json_encode($array);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/json"));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);

    $jsonExec = curl_exec($curl);
    $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    curl_close($curl);
    $resposta = json_decode($jsonExec, true);

    echo "Status: $status\n";
    echo $resposta;
}
```

E para usá-la, faça assim:

```
enviarSMS('foo@bar', '123baz', '2799999999', 'mensagem');
```

Comment: Vlw, resolveu meu problema!

Answer (score 2):

Experimente com [curl](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.curl.php):

```
function do_sms($serv) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $serv);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1');
    $return = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $return;
}

do_sms('https://site.com/apiJSON.php?data={"login":"email@email.com.br","senha":"SENHA","campanha":"ID 1234","mensagens":{"1":{"numero":"2799999999","msg":"MINHA MENSAGEM","data":"2016-08-11 09:20:00"}}}');
```

Ou [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php):

```
file_get_contents('https://site.com/apiJSON.php?data={"login":"email@email.com.br","senha":"SENHA","campanha":"ID 1234","mensagens":{"1":{"numero":"2799999999","msg":"MINHA MENSAGEM","data":"2016-08-11 09:20:00"}}}');
```

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente use o CURL para se conectar com outro serviço.

Dessa forma, por exemplo:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link_para_chamar);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, '10');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);

// Habilita cache do DNS (remover o // para habilitar):
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_DNS_USE_GLOBAL_CACHE, true);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT, '3600');

// Habilita verificação de SSL (em caso de problema defina ambos para FALSE, não é recomendado desligar!):
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);


$resposta = curl_exec($ch);
$erroSite = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) !== 200 ? true : false;
$erroCurl = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Então, para definir o `$link_para_chamar`, utilize `json_encode`:

```
$json = [];
$json['login'] = 'email@email.com.br';
$json['senha'] = 'senha';
$json['campanha'] = 'ID 1234';

$json['mensagens'][1]['numero'] = '2799999999';
$json['mensagens'][1]['msg'] = 'MENSAGEM';
$json['mensagens'][1]['data'] = '2016-08-11 09:20:00';

$link_para_chamar = 'https://site.com/apiJSON.php?data='.json_encode($json);
```

Answer (score -1):

Só implementando o que o amigo acima ressaltou.

Para que fique mais completo, use javascript. Exemplo.

```
<form id="send">
  <input type="text" name="login" />
  <input type="text" name="number" />
</form>
```

E no arquivo javascript recuperar os dados e passar para o Curl no PHP.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'arquivo.php',
  data: $(this).seriaze(),
  type: 'POST'
});
```

E depois é só recuperar os dados no PHP.